# IdentityServer4 signin-oidc page is redirecting to login page infinitely

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am trying to implement a custom Login button on my MVC app that will direct to the IdentityServer for login and then redirect back to my MVC app.

To do this, I'm using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ChallengeAsync` extension method on `HttpContext` in my `Account/Login` action

```
public Task Login()
{
    return HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

The request is directed to the authorize endpoint on the IDP, the user can login and the request is redirected to signin-oidc on my MVC app. It's at this point that signin-oidc calls the `Account/Login` action and starts looping infinitely.

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:4500/Account/Login
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action methodLanding.Controllers.AccountController.Login (Landing) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: OpenIdConnect was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action Landing.Controllers.AccountController.Login (Landing) in 11.9704ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 23.4211ms 302
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://localhost:4500/signin-oidc application/x-www-form-urlencoded 1488
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[10]
      AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 10.4219ms 302
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:4500/Account/Login
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action methodLanding.Controllers.AccountController.Login (Landing) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
```

I assume signin-oidc cannot save the cookie and is assuming the login was unsuccessful. The relevant config for the MVC app looks like this

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    options.Authority = Constants.Authority;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;

    options.ClientId = "mvc";

    options.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

On the IDP, the client is registered as so

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "mvc",
    ClientName = "MVC Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    RequireConsent = false,

    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:4500/signin-oidc" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:4500/signout-callback-oidc" },

    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
    },
}
```

How can I get this flow with `ChallengeAsync` to work correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To anyone looking at this in the future: There is an overload of ChallengeAsync that allows you to pass in a redirectUrl that you want signin-oidc to send the user to after successful login. Once this is set, the infinite redirect doesn't occur.

```
return HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties
{
    RedirectUri = "/",
});
```

Comment: May i know where this code segment needs to be placed ?

Comment: @ArshathShameer This is in your controller action. For me I put it in the Account controller and the Login action.

Comment: Ok thanks and I don't know if you have come across this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452990/redirecting-url-from-identity-server-4-is-not-behaving-as-expected) but if you have an idea please suggest me as an answer.