# Redirecting url from Identity server 4 is not behaving as expected and "Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken" error

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, openid-connect

Note : After resolving the redirection issue i had an another issue that is getting an error "Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken". So in my answer I have provided the correct solution for both.

I have identity server project and the client project, everything works up to authentication without any issues and even it redirects to the correct client url but the url ex : "https://localhost:44309/signin-oidc" gives the blank page.

Note : SSl enabled for Identity Server and Client application.

It is authenticating the user as expected as you can see below in the screen shot.
[image]
My Identity server contains the following config values for client.

```
                // OpenID Connect hybrid flow and client credentials client (MVC)
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "mvc",
                ClientName = "MVC Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                RedirectUris = { /*"http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",*/"https://localhost:44309/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { /*"http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc",*/"https://localhost:44309/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowedScopes = 
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    //"api1"
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            }
```

The startup.cs is as follows.

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());

        services.AddAuthentication()
            //.AddGoogle("Google", options =>
            //{
            //    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

            //    options.ClientId = "434483408261-55tc8n0cs4ff1fe21ea8df2o443v2iuc.apps.googleusercontent.com";
            //    options.ClientSecret = "3gcoTrEDPPJ0ukn_aYYT6PWo";
            //})
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "dataVail Login", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

                options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

                options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/d0e2ebcc-0961-45b2-afae-b9ed6728ead7";//"https://demo.identityserver.io/";
                options.ClientId = "f08cc131-72da-4831-b19d-e008024645e4";
                options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "role"
                };
            });
    }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            context.Request.Scheme = "https";
            await next.Invoke();
        });
        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

Here is the startup.cs for my client app

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = "https://localhost:44392/";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = "mvc";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                //options.Scope.Add("api1");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

            });
    }
```

Can anyone please try helping me to sort this out.

Answer (score 4):

I could resolved this with the help of Identity Server 4 folks.
If any one come across this problem here is the solution.

I missed adding "UseAuthentication" in Configure the client MVC pipeline. So after adding that i was redirected as expected and then I had another issue as shown below.

```
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken. at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler1.d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

I'm getting this exception while connecting my application to IdentityServer4 with AzureAD as external authentication provider. My application is using Hybrid flow to connect to IdentityServer4. I get properly redirected to Azure, login, and code and id_tokens are properly issued. This exception is raised in my application when userInfo endpoint is invoked.

In order resolve this I had to remove the claim which has the name twice.

I confirmed that AAD sends two name claims. Removing one of them resolved the problem.

```
var namesClaim = externalUser.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name) ??
                             throw new Exception("Unknown names");

if (namesClaim!=null)
{
    claims.Remove(namesClaim);
}
```

Hope this may help someone.

Comment: Could you please be more specific where the code to remove extra claims would plug in?

Comment: @Ilya If you have the IdentityServer 4 sample downloaded then you should find the place where this snippet code should be placed and the place is in Quickstart.Account.AccountController.FindUserFromExternalProvider() method.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with having multiple roles. Here is the solution for it:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    // ...
    options.Scope.Add("roles");

    // ... using MapJsonKey instead of MapUniqueJsonKey for having 2 or more roles
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(claimType: "role", jsonKey: "role");
});
```